# How to share single packaged application with Multiple Business Unit or Lines of Business so that both see a separate application in single Org

Tags: community, managed-package, package

We have a community-based app on AppExchange. We are using CustomSetting for application configuration.

We have a client who brought our product to his one BU/LOB. Again they would like to buy our same product for different BU/LOB. But the problem is that both BU/LOB have different requirement and require a different configuration to use it but they have single Salesforce Org.

So my question is that do salesforce provide any feature by which we can separate same application to work differently for both BU/LOB. i.e. **Can We provide multitenant like feature in single Org.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single app can only have one instance within an org. This would be like trying to install two copies of Microsoft Office 2017; the system would simply attempt to upgrade it instead of installing two separate copies.

That said, it would be possible to "roll you own" by using a combination of custom settings and/or custom metadata. Basically, you'd have a List Custom Setting that defines various customization that would be set up by the administrator, and then a Hierarchy Custom Setting that your code would examine to determine which configuration should be used for the current logged in user.

You'll have to determine if the R&D for this feature would be worth it, or if they'll have to figure out an alternative, such as using two orgs.